# Is it possible to use : using Windows.UI.Input.Inking; in Windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, digital-signature

I am trying to crete a windows 8.1 universal app ..
on the phone app I want to have a digital signature using Capturing ink data ..

I have seen the :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792131.aspx

a problem appears when i use the : using Windows.UI.Input.Inking;

any one knows why ?
or what the correct way of doing it for windows phone 81 using C# ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows.UI.Input.Inking is only available in windows 8 app. it is not supported in windows 8.1 or Windows phone 8.1 universal apps. see this **requirement** section of [Inking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.input.inking) msdn documentation

Comment: sorry .. I missed that .. thanks a lot >.<  .. can i  do it using the InkPresenter Class